# Best shallow copy of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, copy

When I was reading the vue source code today, I encountered a writing method that I didn't understand.
[view source](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/fbd697a4b6c238147d661026836314862fd09221/packages/runtime-core/src/scheduler.ts#L159)

```js
const deduped = [...new Set(pendingPostFlushCbs)]
```

In my opinion, it is a shallow copy of the array. But why should I convert to Set first，can I have better performance? How should I understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you remove duplicates:

```js
pendingPostFlushCbs = [1,2,5,5,6,8,8,]
const deduped = [...new Set(pendingPostFlushCbs)]
const deduped1 = [...pendingPostFlushCbs]
console.log(deduped)
console.log(deduped1)
```